# asp.net hosting with iis

Tags: asp.net, hosting

i made an asp.net website.  I can access it on the local network but i cant access outside of it.  i have forwarded incoming request from port 80 to my local ip-address and my provider is comcast and i checked thier website and port is not block.  In the IIS manager, i set the default website to run on my local-ip adress and port 80.  I added exceptions to my firewall for port 80 also.  what else do i need to do?

heres how i try to access the website from outside the network.  I use whatismyip.com to get the external ip address.  then i type http://whatismyipaddress/default.aspx.  I even tried with different port, nothing work

Comment: sounds like what you've described is everything i would have recommended checking. when you say that nothing works, are you getting a specific error? And you're saying that you can get to the site from another computer on your local area network? If so, I would recommend double-checking your router's port-forwarding and firewall (but you said you already did, so sorry this isn't of more help!)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check to make sure they are setup correctly, but my first guess is that you have setup your domain to point to your computer's local ip address behind the router and that it is not an external IP address. Computers that are not in your network don't know how to find your computer even when they have your IP address.

There are detailed instructions on how to do the whole process here: http://lifehacker.com/160945/ask-lifehacker--host-my-web-site-at-home

I believe the missing link for you is to setup something like DynDNS at http://DynDNS.com. Even though it looks like they don't have a free option at first glance, they do.

Comment: i did port forwarding for incoming request on port 80 to go to my internal ip adress.  Right now i dont have a domain name, to get to my website on the local network, i type my local ip-address.  My attempt to access it from outside is to type my external ip address instead of local ip

Comment: That external IP address is a Comcast IP address. It's probably the IP address of the Comcast router your computer connects to to access the internet. You either need to contact Comcast to get your own external IP address or use something like DynDNS. The link explains the process better than I can.